# kendo-angular-upload: Error event not fired after a 500 Server Error Code

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

In the Front End I use Angular 7 and I try to upload an image using Kendo:

```
        <kendo-upload
          [saveUrl]="uploadSaveUrl"
          [removeUrl]="uploadRemoveUrl"
          [restrictions]="uploadRestrictions"
          [multiple]="false"
          [withCredentials]="false"
          (success)="showSavedSuccess()"
          (error)=showSavedFailed($event)
        >
```

and in the back end I use ASP.NET Core. I use basically the code taken from here (regular Controller type version):
https://www.telerik.com/forums/file-upload-full-example-with-server-side-code

When I try it, the success event is fired. However, if I want to test the errors, instead of

```
return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size, filePath });
```

I use

```
return StatusCode(500);
```

In that case the [`(error)` event](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/upload/api/ErrorEvent/) is not fired and I still get the message `Uploading...` from Kendo. If I check the network, I see clearly the `500 error` message.

I tried to send different responses from the back end (null, ...) but I get the same result with all of them.

By the way, this problem is not related to [this one](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/1573) with a similar title.

What should I fix? Should I return a certain error value from the BE or I have to handle Kendo's module in a different way? I didn't find this information in Kendo's page... Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [error event](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/upload/api/UploadComponent/#toc-error) fires when an upload or remove operation fail. [This is an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aq4l3j-uu9vyp?file=app/app.component.ts).

Status code 500 should never reach the client. [Such exceptions should be handled on the server side](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-troubleshoot-common-http-error-codes). Proper HTTP status codes/errors should be returned from the server.

[These](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/return-http-status-code-from-asp-net-core-methods/) are built-in ASP.NET Core methods for the most common status codes here, in order to fire the error event of the Upload Component. Alternatively, [Angular Interceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) can be used to customize the whole client-server communication. A custom error response can be sent from the custom interceptor component. [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ggneig-fj5x6s?file=app/app.component.ts).

Source: Telerik support team.